# How to run a camera Kivy app in headless mode?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, headless

hope you doing well, I am trying to have a "headless" camera service, but `camera._camera.bind()` looks like not working unless is part of an LayOut, here is an "Almost minimal Camera example with GUI" that is working:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
import time
import PIL
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera

Builder.load_string('''
<CameraClick>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ToggleButton:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: root.camera.play = not root.camera.play
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
    Button:
        text: 'Capture'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'
        on_press: root.capture()
''')


class CameraClick(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.camera = Camera(play=False, resolution=(640, 480))
        self.camera._camera.bind(on_texture=self.capture)

    def capture(self, instance=None):
        '''
        Function to capture the images and give them the names
        according to their captured time and date.
        '''
        camera = instance or self.camera
        print(type(camera), camera)
        texture = camera.texture
        image_data = texture.pixels
        size = texture.size
        fmt = texture.colorfmt.upper()
        timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        pil_image = PIL.Image.frombytes(mode=fmt, size=size, data=image_data)
        pil_image.save("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
        print("Captured")


class TestCamera(App):

    def build(self):
        return CameraClick()


TestCamera().run()
```

And here is my minimal example without GUI that is not working:

```
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
import time
import PIL

def capture(instance):
    camera = instance
    texture = camera.texture
    image_data = texture.pixels
    size = texture.size
    fmt = texture.colorfmt.upper()
    timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
    pil_image = PIL.Image.frombytes(mode=fmt, size=size, data=image_data)
    pil_image.save("IMG_{}.png".format(timestr))
    print("Captured")

c = Camera(play=False, resolution=(640, 480))
c._camera.bind(on_texture=capture)
c.play = True
print("Taking 5 seconds of photos...")
sleep(5)
print("Turning off taking photos")
c.play = False
```

So with the GUI example, when I click on play, that works, which is a simple `camera.play = True` and when I do `camera.play = True` on the minimal Camera without GUI, capture function is never called.

What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: from Matham (see github comment): It seems you're blocking the main kivy thread. You cannot run kivy in a "headless" mode as the gui always needs to run and the main thread cannot be blocked, https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6272#issuecomment-486489264

So I think I need to implement the camera using pyjnius